# React styled-components low performance when state changes on mousemove

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, state, styled-components

I'm trying to implement a parallax animation using react hooks and styled-components but I'm running into some performance issues which I feel are due to constant component rerenders resulting in a janky instead of smooth animation.

These are my component styles, as you can see I use props and state updates to update the component's styles

```
const Card = styled.div`
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow:0 2px 10px rgba( 0,0,0,.3 );
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1),
                            box-shadow .5s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1);
    &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1)  ${props => (`perspective(600px) rotateX(${props.degX}) rotateY(${props.degY})`)};
        box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

`
```

This is the entire component, where I handle rotation calculations for the parallax animations and the event handling.

```
function AppleTvParalaxCard({children, className}) {
    const domRef = useRef();
    const [rotationDegX, setrotationDegX] = useState(0);
    const [rotationDegY, setrotationDegY] = useState(0);

    const handleMouseOver = e => {
        const {y, x, width, height} = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const {pageX, pageY} = e;
        const halfW = width / 2;
        const halfH = height / 2;
        const coorX = halfW - (pageX - x);
        const coorY = halfH- (pageY - (y + window.scrollY));
        var degX  = ( ( coorY / halfH ) * 10 ) + 'deg';
        var degY  = ( ( coorX / halfW ) * -10 ) + 'deg';
        setrotationDegX(degX);
        setrotationDegY(degY);
    }

    const handleMouseOut = e => {
        setrotationDegX(0);
        setrotationDegY(0);
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    domRef.current.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseOver);
    domRef.current.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
    return () => {
            domRef.current.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseOver)
            domRef.current.removeEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut)
        };
    }, [handleMouseOver, handleMouseOut]);

  return (
    <Card
            ref={domRef}
            className={className}
            degX={rotationDegX}
            degY={rotationDegY}
    >
      {children}
    </Card>
  );
}
```

How can I boost performance so that this animation runs smooth?

EDIT: I'm seeing that everytime I move my mouse the event listeners are also removed and added again, this probably doesn't help performance wise.

Comment: is there a reason you aren't just using the `onMouseOver` prop?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out most of the performance issues were caused by having my chrome console open, not exactly sure why.

Also changing the state changes to only one setState:

```
    const [degs, setDegs] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
```

Decreased the amount of rerenders.

The answer by Ed Lucas also helped.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't see the double setState().

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to useEffect specifies which values should be checked for updates, running the useEffect function when one of those values changes.

In order to run your useEffect once, when the component is initially rendered, you should use an empty array for this parameter.

```
useEffect(() => {
...
}, []);
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Comment: This helped but wasn't the biggest problem.